# Cannot Change MySQL password

Tags: mysql, windows, passwords, root, reset

All the questtions and answers here in Stackoverflow are about not knowing to reset the root password.
Which I have already tried following mysql site.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

On trying to do this, the cursor on command line goes to next line and continues to blink endlessly.
No response occours even after an hour.

What is actually happening?
Is there any way to solve this?

Note, I have followed the steps about stopping the service)

Answer (score 1):

For windows I did something like this and it worked for me.

```
C:\> C:\mysql\bin\mysqld-nt --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt
```

where mysql-init.txt

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

if you installed with MySQL Installation Wizard then you might need to add this option during the reset

```
--defaults-file="C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.0\\my.ini"
```

Comment: I did exactly this. But still cmd freezes

Comment: Interesting ... It should work unless mysqld is down. Have you tried to check the logs? It might gives some insight what is happening.